# Как отключить кнопку в JQuery Dialog после нажатия на нее

Tags: javascript, jquery

После нажатия на кнопку OK в JQuery Dialog я запускаю ajax запрос к серверу. Как отключить эту кнопку сразу после нажатия чтобы избежать двойных кликов и соответсвенно повторного запроса к серверу?

```
  $("#dialog-confirm-modif-Pex").dialog({
                        resizable: true,
                        height: 'auto',
                        width: 'auto',
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "Cancel": function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            "OK": function (event) {
                                //event.target.id не установлено                               
                                //event.target.disabled  - undefined, хотя в jsfiddle свойство существует    

                                //так не работает, хотя на jsfiddle работает 
                                //event.target.disabled = true;

                                alert("Enabled!")
                                //changePexWithChilds(result, treeData, response );
                            }
                        }
   });
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s004sz2w/2/)

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, пример в jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте заглушку по типу:

```
 $("#dialog-confirm-modif-Pex").dialog({
                        resizable: true,
                        height: 'auto',
                        width: 'auto',
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "Cancel": function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            "OK": function (event) {
                                //event.target.id не установлено                                    
                                //так не работает
                                //event.target.disabled = true;
                                if (!$(button_ok).hasClass('alreadyClicked')){
                                    $(button_ok).addClass('alreayClicked');
                                    changePexWithChilds(result, treeData, response );
}
}
}
   });
```

`$(button_ok)` только замените на идентификатор кнопки соответственно у вас.Я просто не знаком с *JQuery Dialog* поэтому такое сработает только если диалог этот, ну создается динамически а всегда присутствует на странице. Ну и не забывать обнулять наличие класса при открытии диалога.