# Как предотвратить множественные запросы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть каталог товаров, выполненный на ReactJS+Redux. По клику на товар, срабатывает экшн, который шлет запрос за данными товара на апи. И возникла такая ситуация если прокликать раз 10 быстро один продукт, потом столько же другой. То информация по 2 продукту не засетится в стор до тех пор, пока не пройдут запросы по первому продукту(10 штук). Собственно говоря, хотелось бы как-то от этого уйти. Первые мысли,которые пришли в голову-после клика по продукту до момента ответа с апи, поставить лоадер и ограничить бюзера от списка продуктов, или же поставить delay после клика(этот вариант мне не очень нравится). Может есть еще какие-нибудь способы решения подобной задачи?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отключить кнопку в JQuery Dialog после нажатия на нее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480303/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-jquery-dialog-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5)

Comment: я не хотел бы применять jquery. мне интересно, возможно ли это как-то сделать средствами истого js, или reactjs

Comment: В чем проблема завести булевый флаг `isRequestSent` и во время отправки первого запроса выставлять его в `true`, после получения ответа сбрасывать в `false`?

Comment: Можно завернуть обработчик события в debounce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Первые мысли,которые пришли в голову-после клика по продукту до момента ответа с апи, поставить лоадер

Наиболее оптимальный способ. В state заведите переменную isFetching. При клике на загрузку:

```
setState({isFetching: true}, () => {
  // здесь старт загрузчика, поскольку setState тоже асинхронная функция
  // и вы можете успеть "поймать" несколько быстрых кликов
  myFetchFunction()
    .onSuccess((data) => {
        setState({isFetching: false});
        showData(); 
    })
    .onError((error) => {
        setState({isFetching: false});
        showError(error);
    );
});
```